# how to add folder to subfolder inside existing zip file

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I want to achieve the following (simple) task, but I don't know how...

I have a zip file like this, only containing some folders

**dummy.zip:**

```
/my/dummy/folder/stucture
```

how can I add folders to this dummy.zip file that the newly added files and dirs are located under "/my/dummy/folder/stucture" using the command line (linux)?

**dummy.zip** should look like this afterwards:

```
/my/dummy/folder/stucture/my/new/Dirs
```

[I've made a screenshot to better illustrate what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipqzE.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

To append "archive" to an existing zip file you could use option `-r`:

```
zip -r9 dummy.zip dirs
```

You could crate your zip:

```
$ zip -9 dummy.zip file
```

And later you could add a full dir:

```
$ zip -r9 dummy.zip dirs
```

Or contents of the dir on the same root:

```
$ cd dirs
$ zip -r9 dummy.zip *
```

The `-9` is the compression level, in this case, the maximum.

Comment: all the commands put the new files into the "root" folder of the zip file. There must be an option to tell zip where to put the new files.... its something you can easily do with the zip gui. Can't believe that its such an unusual task....

Comment: I'm looking for something like zip -a -r myOldZip.zip/existing/folder/insideZip/ newFolderToAdd (I'm aware that this line's not working ;) )

Comment: What about creating the directory structure under `existing/folder/...` and then just add the full dir `zip -r file.zip existing `

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original folder which you generated the first zip from, you can add the folder/files you want and then use the option `-u` from the `zip` command.

This option will update the zip with the newly added folders and files, you can use it like:

```
$> mkdir /my/dummy/folder/stucture/my/new/Dirs
$> zip -u dummy.zip /my/dummy
```

Comment: sorry, thats not exactly what I need. In my case the  data to add to the dummy zip file contains a lot of heavy individual files and I can't mess around with the file structure. I only need the the target folders to be added to a certain location in the zip file.  The client needs that to be happy :/